# Vim 'earlier' and 'later' commands are not working as expected

Tags: vim

By first looking at the command for time travelling in Vim i.e. `ea {N}s` and `lat {N}s`, I thought it'll be really simple. But, it's not working for me as expected and now I'm totally confused. This is what happened.

I fired up my Vim, and started writing the following lines

```
say, first line written at time 5
second line written after a pause of 5 seconds may be around time 18
third line again after a pause of 5 seconds around 30
```

So, suppose if I started writing at `00:00:00`, I completed line 1 by `00:00:05`, then I took a pause of `5 seconds`, then completed line 2 by `00:00:18`, then again a pause of around 5 seconds, and completed the final third line by `00:00:30`. Then I thought of going to an earlier state by 5 sec, but when I did **:ea 5s**, I was left with following:

```
say, first line written at time 5
```

The line at the bottom of vim said

```
2 fewer lines; before #2  67 seconds ago
```

and I was really confused. Then, I checked help for the command ea/earlier, and I saw this:

```
:earlier {N}s       Go to older text state about {N} seconds before.
```

What does Vim mean by **about**? Is it not exact? How does it still make any sense at all? Can anybody please explain?

*Note: Time mentioned might vary by 1-2 seconds.*

Answer (score 5):

I think

```
:changes
```

and

```
:undolist
```

should help to understand how the history is actually stored. It's hard to tell from here, exactly how your scenario fails to fulfill your expectations (both are a bit fuzzy). Suffice it to say that when I retraced your edit steps (with timing) I got:

```
change line  col text
    3     1    0 say, first line written at time 5
    2     2    0 second line written after a pause of 5 seconds may be around time 18
    1     3    0 third line again after a pause of 5 seconds around 30
>

number changes  when               saved
     4       4  17:01:19
```

Comment: hmm ..I see ..actually I expected that vim will take me back to a state exactly 5 seconds earlier ..for example, suppose, I write the last line, then pause for 5 seconds, then run the command :ea 5s, then according to my expectation, nothing should have been changed as the file was exactly the same 5 seconds earlier. I think I took the "time travelling" of Vim a bit too literally.

Answer (score 5):

Did you leave *insert mode* after each line?! It's generally considered a best practice to leave insert mode as soon as possible; pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and waiting 5 seconds may not be enough to constitute a new change.

You can force creation of an undo point while inserting (also within a line) via `<C-g>u`.

As @sehe already commented, the `:changes` command is a good starting point. Plugins like [Gundo - Visualize your undo tree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304) (requires Python) or [undotree.vim - Display your undo history in a graph](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4177) (does not) make navigating and recalling the tree easier.

Comment: In my case, I did 3 paste operations with 5-second intervals. Apparently, that doesn't create discrete history