# json.tool shell returned 1 and I lost my vim buffer

Tags: python, json, vim, vi

So I'm happily "hacking" away in the command line using vim. I'm working on some JSON text, I'm deleting objects, trimming down an API response to isolate a snippet to work more closely with.

At some point I'm pretty happy I've cut out all of the rubbish from the JSON and I've only got what I need to carry on working...

So I go ahead and type in `:%!python -m json.tool` and boom.

So my JSON text wasn't a valid JSON text after I poked around with it, looks like I forgot a comma somewhere.

```
:%!python -m json.tool
shell returned 1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So I hit enter or any other key and then my buffer is replaced with a nice error message...

```
Expecting , delimiter: line 3 column 5 (char 20)
```

Oh so I did forget a comma, on line 3, thanks!

Oh but where's my JSON text gone? And that ladies and gentlemen is what I seek help with. This is usually where I `:q!` and reopen the JSON file and try to get it right this time. But surely I must be able to recover my buffer from just BEFORE I had the audacity to try and use the python json tool to format a blob of non-JSON text!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `'makeprg'` and `'errorformat'` so you can just run `:make` to do [linting](https://coderwall.com/p/vptnnw/vim-errorformat-setting-for-json-syntax-checker).

```
autocmd FileType json setlocal makeprg=python\ -mjson.tool\ 2>&1\ %\ >\ /dev/null
                     \| setlocal errorformat=%m:\ line\ %l\ column\ %c\ %.%#
```

However, if you are like me and your json buffers are usually scratch buffers then use `setqflist()` to populate the quickfix list.

```
call setqflist([], ' ', {'efm':'%m: line %l column %c %.%#', 'lines': systemlist('python -mjson.tool', getline(1, '$'))})
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'makeprg'
:h 'errorformat'
:h setqflist()
:h systemlist()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you like undo then you'll LOVE this one. The earlier command. Type `:ea` and then the number of seconds you want to go back in time and hit enter. The opposite of this is the later command, `:lat`.

However I must warn you that this time is only **approximate** and it is recommended that you leave insert mode as often as possible . It's generally easier to use undo and redo.

[Vim 'earlier' and 'later' commands are not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511451/vim-earlier-and-later-commands-are-not-working-as-expected)